# SQL Query to grab first row of new ID value and then sum the count of the repeated ID value

Tags: sql, ms-access

Suppose I have a table of this form:

```
ID Value      Data
   1            A
   1            B
   1            C
   2            Q
   2            J
   3            D
```

I'd like the query to return...

```
 A (3 total)
 Q (2 total)
 D (1 total)
```

So as the title says, I want to grab the value of 'Data' for the first time that there is a change in ID Values. There are three ID Values of 1, and the first value of Data is A, so it returns A (3 total). There are two ID values of two, and the first value of Data is Q, so I return Q (2 total), etc.

I'm doing this on a website so I have a little freedom in how I print things out. I'm currently doing two queries, and then printing them together with a simple printf (the real data has more columns of data than what was in the example above).

```
    $sql = "SELECT COUNT(VIN)
    AS vinCount 
    FROM TestTable 
    WHERE (JobNumber='$jobNum') AND (AssignedEmp='$EmpName')
    GROUP BY WorkOrderNumber";
```

In this example, WorkOrderNumber plays the role of ID Value, and I am trying to sum the number of VIN's

This grabs the correct number ('3 total' for example) every time, without fail.

My real issue is grabbing the first row values (A, Q, D in the example posed above). The problem is that **I cannot have a 'where WorkOrderNumber=' statement since beforehand I don't know what they are.** They are user generated, so I'm having to look them up.

Is there something I'm overlooking? Here's the query I first tried which obviously won't work.

```
    $sql = "SELECT FIRST (JobStage + ' ' + WorkItem + ' ' + VIN + ' ' + Make + ' ' + Model + ' ' + ExColor) 
    AS WorkSelection 
    FROM TestTable 
    WHERE (JobNumber='$jobNum') AND (AssignedEmp='$EmpName')";
```

Is there some sort of WHERE clause I can add onto this which would logically be equivalent to 'if this is a not before seen value of WorkOrderNumber, grab it'?

EDIT: I ended up doing this....

```
    //Grab number of cars
    $sql = "SELECT COUNT(VIN)
    AS vinCount 
    FROM TestTable 
    WHERE (JobNumber='$jobNum') AND (AssignedEmp='$EmpName')
    GROUP BY WorkOrderNumber";

    $number = odbc_exec($connection, $sql);                             

    //Grab car description
    $sql = "SELECT (tmp.JobStage + ' ' + WorkItem + ' ' + VIN + ' ' + Make) AS WorkSelection
    FROM ( SELECT JobStage, WorkItem, VIN, Make FROM TestTable WHERE (JobNumber='$jobNum') AND (AssignedEmp='$EmpName')) AS tmp";


    $rs = odbc_exec($connection, $sql);

    while(odbc_fetch_row($number)){
        odbc_fetch_row($rs);
        odbc_fetch_row($rs);
        $count = odbc_result($number, 'vinCount');
        $row = odbc_result($rs, 'WorkSelection');
        //$row = odbc_result($rs, 'WorkSelection');
        printf("<option value='%s'>(%s other cars) %s</option>", $row, $count, $row);
    }
```

Just split it into two queries and then printed them out together.

Comment: What is your DBMS (SQL Server, MySql, Oracle, etc.)? Does it support `PIVOT`?

Comment: It's an Access database, and from what I've heard its SQL functionality is a bit limited.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming MSSQL:

```
WITH cte As
(
  SELECT
    -- NB: Replace the "ID" in "ORDER BY ID" 
    -- with the real column you're sorting on:
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY ID) As RowNumber,
    COUNT(1) OVER (PARTITION BY ID) As NumberOfRows,
    Data
  FROM
    TestTable
)
SELECT
  Data,
  NumberOfRows
FROM
  cte
WHERE
  RowNumber = 1
```

http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/34385/1

Comment: It's giving me this error:

Syntax error (missing operator) in query expression 'ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY WorkOrderNumber ORDER BY WorkOrderNumber)'

Any idea what could be wrong there? I'm pretty sure it's transcribed over exactly. Maybe my version of SQL doesn't support these methods

Comment: @Hoser: Glad to hear you got it working. The query I posted was for MSSQL; at the time, you hadn't specified which DBMS you were using. Given the limitations of Access, I'm surprised this was even close!

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
SELECT
    tmp.Data,
    COUNT(Table.ID)
FROM(
    SELECT
        ID,
        Data
    FROM Table 
    GROUP BY 
        ID
) as tmp
INNER JOIN Table
    ON Table.ID = tmp.ID
GROUP BY 
    tmp.Data
```

But this will work on mysql since in mysql the inner query where i group by ID the value of Data will be the first encounter just like you want but on other DBMS like oracle or sql server i don't think it will work.

Comment: Thank you, I'll give this a try. I don't mind too much if the return value isn't the very first encounter, so if it doesn't do that it'll be okay.

Comment: It keeps giving me an error, stating that I'm not including JobStage as part of an aggregate function. The problem seems to be in the second SELECT ID, Data... portion of the query